# Django prevent superuser from seeing data in /change/ page

Tags: django

I'm using Django 2.1.5 and have been using the `list_display` in `ModelAdmin`-based classes to limit what our superusers can see in the admin pages. There is some sensitive data that only the user should have access to.

Say I have a app based on model `SensitiveObject` with `id`, `name`, `secret`, etc., I can simply exclude `secret` from the `list_display` and it will never show up in the Admin page. However, when I browse to `/admin/full/myapp/sensitiveobject/` I will have a list of those object IDs and can simply go to `/admin/.../sensitiveobject/<id>/change/` which will show all of the fields, including the ones that I excluded from `list_display`.

Is there a way to limit what I'm seeing in the /change/ endpoint, as well?

Comment: Which users would you like to see these fields? Is it dynamic based on the user viewing the instance?

Answer (score 1):

The [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) attribute of your [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) is what defines the fields that are displayed on the change form for each object.

You can make this dynamic you can override the method [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields):

```
def get_fields(request, obj=None):
    fields = []  # Default list of fields
    if request.user.passes_some_test():
        fields.append()  # The secret field
    return fields
```